# convert into list of attachment

Tags: apex, list

i am using below syntax.How to convert it into list of attachment.

```
Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = pageCP.Id, name = fixedFileName, body = profilePicFile, contenttype='image/jpg');
```

i want something like :

```
list<Attachment> a = new list<Attachment>(parentId = pageCP.Id, name =
fixedFileName, body = profilePicFile, contenttype='image/jpg');
```

Comment: `list<account> a = new List<account>{new Account(name='xyz'), new Account(name = 'abc')};`

Comment: Attachment a = new Attachment(new attachment(parentId = pageCP.Id, name = fixedFileName, body = profilePicFile, contenttype='image/jpg'));       
 It is throwing error saying SObject constructor must use name=value pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
list<Attachment> a = new List<Attachment>{new attachment(parentId = pageCP.Id, name = fixedFileName, body = profilePicFile, contenttype='image/jpg')};
```